# How to set cookie in Javascript and fetch it in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am very confused how to set cookie in Javascript and than fetch it in jsp, I have tried a lot but all im vain

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> js code to add cookie

```
document.cookie = "username=Chirag; expires=Fri, 16 Mar 2018 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";
```

> and to retrive cookie add this to your jsp code

```
<%
    Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
    String username = null;
    for(Cookie cookie : cookies) {
        if("username".equals(cookie.getName())){
            username = cookie.getValue();
        }
    }
%>
```

additional resources
[Cookie in JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)